# When Clicking Submit My Browser goes to domain.com/contactform.php insted of running php

Tags: php, html, forms

I hosted my website through Hostinger. I inserted a PHP form on my website to send an email using my mail id. But when I am testing this feature on `domainname.com/contactform.php`, system show blank screen instead of running the code. I tried to solve my issue but I can not find my mistake. Please Help!

```
<div class="col-md-6 padding">
                            <!-- banner form -->
                            <form action="contactform.php" method="post">
                                <h5 class="mb-3">Register Here</h5> 
                                <div class="form-style-w3ls">
                                    <input placeholder="Your Name" name="name" type="text" required="">
                                    <input placeholder="Your Email Id" name="email" type="email" required="">
                                    <input placeholder="Contact Number" name="number" type="text" required="">
                                    <select>
                                      <option value="0">Business Type</option>
                                      <option value="1">Corporate</option>
                                      <option value="1">Partnership</option>
                                      <option value="1">Other</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <!--<input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" required=""> -->
                                    <button Class="btn" name="submit"> Submit</button>
                                    <span>By Registering, You agree to Our <a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions.</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

PHP Form

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $MailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $contactnumber = $_POST['number'];
    $Businesstype = $_POST['type'];

    $mailTo = "care@thecraftedu.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$MailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an Email from ".$name.".\n\n".$contactnumber;

    mail($mailTo, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
}

?>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `header("Location: ....`, you wrote hea**r**der.

Comment: Hi Julien, I changed the same in the server but it is still having the same problem.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  at the top of your file (below the `<?php`) to get the error message if any. Note that this sould never be there in production so remove it once you figured out the issue.

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice, the format for mail is `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)`, you seem to be missing either the subject or the message. Also your `<select>` is missing a `name` attribute (which makes `$_POST['type']` invalid) and there are 3 `<option>s with a value of 1

Comment: Hi Julien that really helped I missed a semicolon in one line thankyou very much. Now my php works and it is sending me email although after clicking submit the browser is giving 404 error. what should I do.

Comment: Thanks @kerbh0lz I didn't understand how to capture the type kind of input so that's where I am stuck. although can you help me with that.

Comment: Use something like `<select name="type"><option value="business">Business Type</option><option value="corporate">Corporate</option>...</select>`